# Retrieving image from access DB

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

i need help with this , here is my code. and i have a picture box in my form. but everytime i run the program. i cant retrieve the image from the access. and also i have multiple picture box coz i need to retrieve all images from other tables so here is an example of my code to retrieve one of the tables. thank you.

```
Private Sub p1()

    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        con.Open()

    End If

    With aAdapter

        .SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()

        .SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT [president],[prespic] FROM president WHERE presnum= '" & pcount1.Text & "'"

        .SelectCommand.Connection = con

    End With

    Dim dataRead As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    dataRead = aAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader()

    If (dataRead.Read() = True) Then
        pres1.Text = (dataRead("president"))
        Dim x As Byte() = dataRead("prespic")
        Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(x)
        Me.prespic1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

    End If

    Com = con.CreateCommand
    Dim num As Integer
    Com.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(vote.presnum) from vote where presnum= '" & pcount1.Text & "'"
    If IsDBNull(Com.ExecuteScalar) Then
        pres1.Visible = False
        pnum1.Visible = False
    Else
        num = Com.ExecuteScalar
        pnum1.Text = num
    End If
    Com.Dispose()
    con.Close()
    aAdapter.Dispose()
End Sub
```

here is my code for saving.

```
Dim fsreader As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        Dim breader As New BinaryReader(fsreader)

        Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.Length) As Byte
        breader.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.Length)
        fsreader.Close()


        If Not dataRead.HasRows Then

            ComInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO president([presnum],[president],[prespic])" & _
                "VALUES('" & pnum.Text & "','" & prestxt.Text & "','" & "@d7" & "')"

            Com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d7", imgbuffer)

            ComInsert.Connection = con
            ComInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MsgBox("New Candidate Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "NEW RECORD")

            prestxt.Text = ""

            aAdapter.Dispose()
            ComInsert.Dispose()
            Com.Dispose()
            Call newcount()
        Else
            MsgBox("WARNING: Candidate Already Exist in the Record!!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "ERROR SAVING DATA")
        End If
```

Comment: You've not said what the problem actually is, just that there is one.

Comment: i said it there. my problem sir is that i cant see the image being retrieved to the picture box. in short i cant retrieve the image using this code.

Comment: Are you storing this image as Long Binary Data?

Comment: yes. it is stored as long binary data.

Comment: Try the answer I have provided, this should do it if your data is indeed in binary format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INSERT query is borked.  Always use parameters in all cases.  You tried to use a parameter for your image field, but you ended up passing it a string call `"@d7"` instead of a parameter named `@d7`.

```
ComInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO president ([presnum],[president],[prespic])" & _
            "VALUES(@pnum, @ptxt, @d7)"

ComInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pnum", pnum.Text)
ComInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptxt", prestxt.Text)
ComInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d7", imgbuffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot and let me know how it works out for you?

```
    Dim x As Byte() = DirectCast(dataRead("prespic"), Byte())
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(x)
    Me.prespic1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    ms.Dispose()
```

This should do it, that is if your storing this as binary data...

Comment: sad to here it's not working. btw . ill add my code from my save data

Comment: i edited my question and the code for my saving is there. thank you so much